# Segmentation fault runtime error when attempting to iterate through a vector to print it out

Tags: c++

Here I have the whole piece of code. The aim of this piece of code is to accept space separated values, reverse the order and then print them back out, space separated.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    int x = input.length();
    vector<char> arr;
    for(int z; z==x; z=z+2){
        arr.push_back(input[z]);
    }
    int i = arr.size();
    for(int a = 0; a==i; a++){
        cout << arr[a] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this, in VSCode, I get not error when compiling but a runtime error: **11086 segmentation fault**. As far as I am aware, a segmentation fault is something to do with me accessing memory that I do not have access to however I am slightly confused since I have not utilised any pointers here.

I have done a bit of testing and I have narrowed down the problem to this iteration of the vector that is causing the memory issue:

```
int i = arr.size();
for(int a = 0; a==i; a++){
    cout << arr[a] << " ";
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this block of code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `int z` is uninitialized and you're using it, so undefined behavior.

Comment: Your loop conditions are also most certainly wrong. Even if you get a single iteration you would access `arr` out of bounds

Comment: A for loop stops when the condition is false, not when it is true.

Comment: The condition in the first loop is never true, so `arr` is left empty. The condition in the second loop is true exactly once, so you're trying to access the first element of an empty vector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've not initialized variable `z` and you're using its value which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/ad9MYVHbV) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Uw4rjFZN0pAMCiOC) it crashes.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

**Additionally**, the conditions used in your for loop doesn't fit the description that you gave at the beginning of your question. It would be better to work out the logic on paper first and then implement it.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: Hmm okay. I assumed that int z; in the for loop brackets actually declared the variable. Okay I'll retry it now

Comment: @DarklySpaced Wherever you're accessing an elements inside the array, make sure that you don't go out of bounds of that array otherwise the program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @DarklySpaced _"I assumed that int z; in the for loop brackets actually declared the variable"_: yes it _declares_ the variable, but it doesn't _initialize_ it.

Answer (score -1):

Like others already pointed out, you forgot to initialize `z` in the first for loop. Usually in debug build/mode not initialized variables will be initialized with its default value. <strike>The default value of an integer is 0. Therefore in debug you program works.</strike> EDIT: Jabberwocky corrected me in the comments.
On other hand in release build `z` is initialized with a random number. It will be any number depending on the current memory state at the variables position on the stack.
Usually VSCode should show a warning like C4701. You should always check and fix all compiler warnings.

Comment: _"Usually in debug build/mode not initialized variables will be initialized with its default value. The default value of an integer is 0."_: this is blatantly wrong. Debug builds will certainly not default initialize `int` variables with 0. Either they don't initialize them at all (just like in release builds) or they initialize them with some special pattern like `0xcccccccc` that can be easily recognized.

Comment: https://whtaguy.com/2019/05/21/What-Value-Is-Stored-In-Uninitialized-Variables-3F.html